# why is the submit button leading to other tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a dummy message on top of "To:" read only inout box after clicking a Send Mail button in mail tab as shown below. [image: mailtab] 
But what's happening is instead of displaying message, it opens "**FAQ**" tab. Can you suggest me on how can I display a message on top of input box without going to FAQ tab. Thank you.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/HebleV/pen/vZYvGb)

```
 $("#frmDemo").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var comment = $("#comment").val();
  if(name == "" || comment == "" ) {
  $("#error_message").show().html("All Fields are Required");
  } else {
 $("#error_message").html("").hide();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "post-form.php",
  data: "name="+name+"&comment="+comment,
  success: function(data){
    $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
    }, 2000 );

  }
});
}
});
```

Comment: Can you please check the href of the button ?

Comment: [idiot idea] try to `return false` at the end to stop any propagation is maybe a solution ?

Comment: [idiot idea] You should `.focus()` on the wrong field to be sure

Comment: personnally i dont see the error happens.. Check if your #error_message or #success_message are uniq id in the page, or if you dont have any other `.submit()` function somewhere..

Comment: I haven't given any href attribute in submit but it still lands into other tab

Comment: @HebleV Try to stop propagation, `e.stopPropagation()` and `return false` at the end of the function

Comment: @Pirs It didn't work

Comment: @HebleV The codepen works well, i think the issue comes from another script, or i dont see

Comment: @Pirs Yes I saw it. But thats all the code is. No other script. And it still goes to FAQ tab

Comment: I discovered why its happening. Its because of the form tag which will try to pass the data regardless. When I removed the form tags, its not switching anywhere but just displaying plain onclick innerhtml data.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
$("form#frmDemo").submit(function(e) {

  let t = $(this);
  let name = t.find("#name").val();
  let comment = t.find("#comment").val();
  let errorMsg = t.find("#error_message");
  let successMsg = t.find("#success_message");

  if(name == "" || comment == "" ) {

    errorMsg.html("All Fields are Required").show();

  } else {

    errorMsg.html("").hide();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "post-form.php",
      data: "name="+name+"&comment="+comment,
      success: function(data){
        successMsg.fadeIn().html(data);
        setTimeout(function() {
          successMsg.fadeOut("slow");
        }, 2000 );

      }
    });

  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It didnt work. Can a dummy message be displayed just on click of a button?

Comment: Edit :  i read the state of the page change the tabs with ajax, and the preventDefault should be at the end of the script, try it plz